# Is it possible to create a display only calendar?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, calendar

I have a master calendar that links to multiple other calendars to show time off for the different teams in my IT department. Currently, there are seperate calendars for each department, which requires the user to go to their specific team's calendar to add their time off to the calendar.

Is there a way I can make it so people can't add events on the master calendar to help avoid confusion? Or even a way that they can add events to the master calendar that will then be added to the appropriate team calendar?

Answer (score 0):

You may use Sharepoint Designer Workflow approach,

1. Create a Choice field which hold the value of different departments in the Master Calendar. If it is already present then it is great. Make thge column mandatory
2. Create  a SharePoint Designer list workflow for Master calendar list, which will get triggered on Adding of the item.
3. Based on the user selection of department, create item in the corresponding child calendar list using the workflow